# How would I go about solving this

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone solve all of the parts of this question?

The first three terms of an infinite sequence are k+4, k+2 and 4

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear what the question means. There are many possible answers if all that is required is to produce a squence whose first three terms are $k+4,k+2,4$. Here is one 'solution' $$a_1=k+4, a_2=k+2, a_n=2(a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}), \text { for }n \ge 3.$$ But $$b_1=k+4, b_2=k+2, b_n=(a_{n-2}-a_{n-1})^2, \text { for }n \ge 3.$$ is also a solution and so is $$c_1=k+4, c_2=k+2,c_3=4, c_n=\sqrt {17+ \pi}, \text { for }n \ge 4.$$  Unless more information is given, the question is not amathematical one but one about the psychology of the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

If it is linear, then
$(k+2)-(k+4)
=4-(k+2)
$
or
$-2 = 2-k$
or
$k = 4$.

Check:
8, 6, 4.

If it is geometric, then
$\dfrac{k+2}{k+4}
=\dfrac{4}{k+2}
$
or
$k^2+4k+4
=4k+16$
or
$k^2 = 12$
or
$k = \pm 2\sqrt{3}$.

I'll let you check this.